# Etiqueta emergente

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

Como puedo hacer para que al posicionar el cursor encima de un botón del componente menú debajo del menú aparezca una etiqueta con información particular de ese botón en REACT?...

Comment: con css hover y mucho cuidado

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Las preguntas sin el código relacionado no son bien recibidas porque pones a la gente a adivinar. Los voluntarios no van a armar tooodo un ejemplo para explicarte; si tú provees tu escenario y el código que no te funciona junto con los errores o detalles que no funcionan, te van a responder muchísimo más rápido. Ve a [edit] y mejora tu pregunta.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.